# What does "eksctl create iamserviceaccount" do under the hood on an EKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-iam, eks

AWS supports [IAM Roles for Service Accounts (IRSA)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) that allows cluster operators to map AWS IAM Roles to Kubernetes Service Accounts.

To do so, one has to create an [iamserviceaccount](https://eksctl.io/usage/iamserviceaccounts/) in an EKS cluster:

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
    --name <AUTOSCALER_NAME> \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --cluster <CLUSTER_NAME> \
    --attach-policy-arn <POLICY_ARN> \
    --approve \
    --override-existing-serviceaccounts
```

The problem is that I don't want to use the above `eksctl` command because I want to declare my infrastructure using `terraform`.

Does eksctl command do anything other than creating a service account? If it only creates a service account, what is the `YAML` representation of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It does more than just creating a service account. It does three things:

1. It Creates an IAM role.
2. It attaches the desired iam-policy (--attach-policy-arn
   <POLICY_ARN>) to the created IAM role.
3. It creates a new kubernetes service account annotated with the arn of the created IAM role.

Now It's easy to declare the above steps using kubernetes and aws providers in terraform.